# ERROR while installing "swirl" package in Rstudio

Tags: r, swirl

### i tried to install "swirl" but i got this error

ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘openssl’
* removing ‘/home/mahmoudelshaer/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.6/openssl’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘openssl’ had non-zero exit status
* installing *source* package ‘RCurl’ ...
** package ‘RCurl’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
checking for curl-config... no
Cannot find curl-config
ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘RCurl’
* removing ‘/home/mahmoudelshaer/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.6/RCurl’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘RCurl’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependencies ‘curl’, ‘openssl’ are not available for package ‘httr’
* removing ‘/home/mahmoudelshaer/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.6/httr’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘httr’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependencies ‘httr’, ‘RCurl’ are not available for package ‘swirl’
* removing ‘/home/mahmoudelshaer/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.6/swirl’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘swirl’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/tmp/RtmpkcuO45/downloaded_packages’

> library("Swirl")
>   Error in library("Swirl") : there is no package called ‘Swirl’

i also tried solution from other similar question 
sudo dnf install libssl-dev
Last metadata expiration check: 0:18:30 ago on Wed 27 May 2020 11:37:04 AM EET.
No match for argument: libssl-dev
Error: Unable to find a match: libssl-dev

Answer (score 0):

I solve it
As a Fedora 32 user, i run those commands in terminal and they solved my problem

### 1st

sudo dnf install libcurl4-openssl-dev

### 2nd

sudo dnf groupinstall 'Development Tools' 'Development Libraries'

### 3rd

sudo dnf install zlib-devel libyaml-devel openssl-devel gdbm-devel readline-devel ncurses-devel libffi-devel curl git openssh-server redis libxml2-devel libxslt-devel libcurl-devel libicu-devel python

### then in RStudio i typed

install.packages("swirl", dependencies = TRUE)
and it worked successfully

### to check##

> library("swirl")

| Hi! Type swirl() when you are ready to begin.